# Does Java Git API (JGit or others) Support finding renamed files between commits?

Tags: api, rename, diff, git-diff, jgit

Does Java Git API, Example JGit support finding files between two commits that were renamed?

As example with command line git if I use `git status` I could see a view along the lines of

```
renamed: old-file-name -> new-file-name
```

I would like to get the same functionality (finding old name and new name) but from a java API call.

Answer (score 0):

With JGit you can fetch diffs between arbitrary commits, branches and tags and get old-path and new-path for changed files. For these you can check if the path is different.

When performing a Diff, the class `DiffEntry` provides `oldPath` and `newPath` which you can compare.

See JavaDoc for [DiffEntry.getOldPath()](https://javadoc.io/static/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit/6.1.0.202203080745-r/org.eclipse.jgit/org/eclipse/jgit/diff/DiffEntry.html#getOldPath()) and [DiffEntry.getNewPath()](https://javadoc.io/static/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit/6.1.0.202203080745-r/org.eclipse.jgit/org/eclipse/jgit/diff/DiffEntry.html#getNewPath()) for the exact semantics.

The [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook) has a ready-to-run code-snippet [DiffRenamedFile.java](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/DiffRenamedFile.java), the check for renaming is done [here](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/DiffRenamedFile.java#L67).